# Git Commits, Pushes and Files overwrite

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-commit

- I'm working with two branches | BranchOne and BrancheTwo
- My friend is working on BranchThree.

My friend has made a lot of commits, I can see the commits on remote repository but the files have not been replaced.

To show the commits on the repository (github/gitbucket/....), I need to `PUSH` my `commits`, right ?

But how the files did not get replaced? Only pushes from `master`  will replace the files ?

So after I'm sure the work on Branch2 and Branch3 are done, I just `merge` them to master? and `push` it ?

Comment: You can select the branch you want to browse on GitHub and Bitbucket. Dropdown with branches list is right over the files list on the left side.

Comment: I know. It's already "All branches" ;P Only push from `Master` will replace/overwrite the files?

Comment: Every Git branch is completely separate state of the file system. Pushes to each branch changes its corresponding state. You can switch between states using dropdown on the GitHub/Bitbucket. And dropdown can't be "All branches". By default it says "master", but you can switch to any branch and browse this branches state (what you call *replacing files*).

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin So the thing here is: I create a branch to fix a specific problem and when it's 100% function, I merge it to master? 

Thank you man!+1

Comment: Yes, this is correct.